# macOS Screen Saver performance issues

Tags: macos, screensaver

I've used the Xcode project template to create a macOS Screen Saver, with similar iOS and macOS targets. They all perform the same series of drawing and animation, primarily using Core Animation and `CALayers`.

The macOS and iOS apps that run independently run perfectly. But when run as a screen saver (using the `ScreenSaverView` of the `ScreenSaver` framework) for a long period of time (several hours), all the animations lock up, and the system becomes so clogged that I can't even dismiss the screen saver. It's as if there is some memory or graphics leak, but this isn't evident when running in other environments. I've also tried profiling all the targets in Instruments to no avail.

Can anyone think of any possibilities as to why this issue is occurring just with the screen saver?

Comment: Are there a lot of layers?

Comment: @matt Yes I should have mentioned, there is anywhere up to 2,000 layers at a time.

Comment: That's it then.

Comment: @matt It still doesn't make sense that this only happens when running as a screen saver?

Comment: You are asking it to recompose the entire massive layer render tree on every frame. The screen saver world can't handle that.